# How to add favicon to an ASP page

Tags: html, asp.net, favicon

I want to add an favicon to my web application.

I've added this in the site.master page:

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

It is only working, when I run the application via Visual Studio.

If i start the app from IIS (for example) the favicon is not displayed.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The `favicon.ico` file must be in the same directory as your html file in the server.

Comment: it's in the same directory, sure.

Comment: Use your absolute URL then.

Comment: Also try clearing the cache, or load from a different browser

Comment: @helderdarocha if i use the absolute URL i don't see the favicon from the Visual Studio Too. And i've cleared the cache and used another browser but still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the same favicon to the whole site, there's no need to add any markup to the site - just ensure the file exists at `http://yoursite/favicon.ico`

If you need to have different favicons for different parts of the same site, then you will need to use the markup.